# FullCalendar Event Display Setting according to time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) in my project, problem is that when I add an event with, let say,

```
start: "04/18/2018 22:05:00",
end : "04/19/2018 02:05:00"
```

above date and time have time difference of 4 hours but dates end date is the next day,

I want that in the above situation event should display in two days (04/18/2018 - 04/19/2018) in month view of calendar. But it shows only in one day (04/18/2018) in this situation.

How can we achieve this? See demo image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is affected by the `nextDayThreshold` option. As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold, in cells which show whole days, such as those found in the "month" and "basic" view types, a multi-day event is only rendered onto its last day if its end time is later than the time specified in `nextDayThreshold`.

By default, this time is `"09:00:00"` (9am).

You can set this option to something more suitable for your situation. e.g. with the sample data given in your question, setting it to midnight (`"00:00:00"`) might be more appropriate, and would cause any events with end times later than midnight (in effect all of them) to always be rendered:

```
nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00"
```

Comment: Thank you ADyson, you are really helpfull.